# Problem with arara in verbose mode

Tags: texlive, arara, java

I'm using TeXLive 2016 and java 1.8.0.111 on Windows 7 Home Premium.

Suppose I'm using arara with the verbose option, as in:

```
arara -v file.tex
```

If `file.tex` contains an error, I get a prompt `?` where I can type the
commands, `e` for editing the file, `x` for ending the output, etc.

But, whenever I type one of those characters I don't see the character
echoed on the cmd window, although the command was executed. So, for
example, if I type `x` I don't see the `x`, although the command itself
was executed.

How can I get the entered commands echoed on the cmd window?

Comment: It seems a problem with the command shell of Windows; it doesn't happen on Unix systems.

Comment: Do you have the same problem if using powershell instead of cmd?

Comment: I can confirm the behaviour partly. When typing s or x I don't see it, but when I hit enter it appears.